# SharePoint 2013 workflows suspended

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I'm in the Workflow Health page, and I see I have several workflow instances suspended with the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. 
Exception details: System.InvalidCastException: The value 'd/results(0)/Assign_x0020_ToId' 
cannot be read as type 'String'
```

I tried resuming them all by clicking "Resume all" from the dialog box, but they are still stuck as "Suspended". Any help will be greatly appreaciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may occur if you are using an action (like start task or whatever) at your workflow that return the `Assigned To` field with default **string** selection.

So try to review your workflow and make sure you the return field `Assigned To` as your requirement as shown below in the drop-down list of `Return field as`

[image]

Comment: I reviewed all my return fields on Designer and reverted all back from String, and I am still getting instances of workflows suspended.

Comment: is it suspended with the same error ?

Comment: Yes. Suspended with the same error. I double checked in Designer and InfoPath to make sure the return type for this field is not a string.

Comment: Would it help if I enable "activate workflow manually" in Designer? Right now now, it is set up to fire up the workflow if a list item is created or changed.

Comment: I think this is not related to your issue , this options to when to start your workflow

Comment: should you explain what's the workflow scenario ? or more detail to can trace the issue ?

Comment: Workflow scenario:

    If Current Item:Status equals PROJECT ASSIGNED (people picker field)
        Email Current Item: Assign To (<-- I changed this to string and set it up back to Display Name because of this issue)

    If Current Item:Status not equals PROJECT ASSIGNED
        
        If Current Item: Status equals PROJECT RECEIVED
        or ... (some other status)
                Email Current Item: Created By

(the rest of the workflow are a series of if/else statements based on STATUS column with EMAIL actions)

Comment: at this Assign To (<-- I changed this to string and set it up back to Display Name because of this issue)  try to select  user IDs not display name , and tell me the result

Comment: I have changed "Return field as: " to "User Ids, Semicolon Delimited" and it did not solve the problem. I still have suspended workflows.

Comment: do you  assign people picker field ? you send email is it right ?

Comment: I am sorry I noticed that  you send an email so  you should use email not display name ! this the last try if not worked so there's another issue raise this error , and in this case, It need to be checked remotely , anyway hope it works

Comment: Yes. Workflow sends email to people(s) contained in the ASSIGN TO people picker. Or it is supposed to do that